# stopPropagation also stopping other sibling events in the same parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I posted something yesterday and it was semi-solved(?) but I'm running into new different problems.

I have page with `Link` surrounding the each row of a component that has two buttons. The `Link` opens up a flyout.

I'm running into a problem with event bubbling and for some reason whenever `stopPropagation` doesn't seem to work with `<Button2 />`. When I hit the `<CopyButton />`, the stopPropagation does its job and stops the flyout from appearing. Whenever I click on `<Button2/>`, its own click handler fires first then the flyout appears.

In addition, it is for some reason causing the entire page to reload by calling the `fetch` in the reducer.

I have tried using a `stopPropagation`, `stopImmediatePropagation`, `preventDefault`, `cancelBubble`, and moving the aforementioned methods into the reducer.

In component

```
<Link to={`/whatever?id=abcme`} onClick={() => loadFlyout()}>
  <div>
    // Second column
  </div>

  <div>
    // Third column
  </div>

  <div className={styles.id}>
    <span>Text</span>
    <span>
        <CopyButton/> 
    </span>
  </div>

  <div>
    // Fifth column
  </div>

  <div>
      <Button2/>
  </div>
</Link>
```

On the page

```
<ComponentwithButtons
  onCopy={e => {
    showToaster();
    setTimeout(() => {
      dismissToaster();
    }, 3000);

    e.preventDefault(); // works
    e.stopPropagation(); // works
  }}
  onClick={e => {
    onButtonClickProp();

    e.preventDefault(); // doesn't work
    e.stopPropagation(); // doesn't work
  }}
/>

<Paginator/>
```

I am new to React and Redux so I'm really struggling with this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Few things I would highlight:

- I can't see onClick on {Button2}
- Add a `console.log(e)` in `onButton2Click` to check it is actually getting the event attribute.
- Not sure what is {onButton2Click}. Is it some custom event?

I have tried to map same implementation here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/compassionate-sea-2phhn with onClick event and it seems to work fine. May be you can compare it with your implementation and see if you are missing something obvious.

Comment: I just edited it to make the onClick more obvious. {OnButton2Click} was the attribute name given to the onClick for that custom component. 

Your example works but I think it's different from what I meant. Sorry that my question wasn't very clear I'm bad at all this React stuff. In my code, the CopyButton works like your example but <Button2 /> doesn't. Also I don't know if this makes a difference but the components are tied to a reducer